# How to customise or disable right click menu on offline plotly plot?

Tags: python, pyqt5, plotly-python, right-click

I am creating an offline plotly plot in a similar manner as this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly

import numpy as np


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # some example data
        x = np.arange(1000)
        y = x**2

        # create the plotly figure
        fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y))

        # we create html code of the figure
        html = '<html><body>'
        html += plotly.offline.plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs='cdn')
        html += '</body></html>'

        # we create an instance of QWebEngineView and set the html code
        plot_widget = QWebEngineView()
        plot_widget.setHtml(html)

        # set the QWebEngineView instance as main widget
        self.setCentralWidget(plot_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

With mouse left click I can access the navigations (like zoom a pan), but the right click is currently absolutely useless for me, so I would like to put my own actions in the right-click menu, or if it is not possible at least disable it. Is there a way in plotly to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the contextMenuEvent method and add the desired QActions and QMenus.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly

import numpy as np


class WebEngineView(QWebEngineView):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = self.page().createStandardContextMenu()
        menu.addSeparator()
        custom_action = menu.addAction("Custom Action")
        custom_action.triggered.connect(self.handle_custom_action)
        menu.exec_(event.globalPos())

    def handle_custom_action(self):
        print("custom_action")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        x = np.arange(1000)
        y = x ** 2

        fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y))

        html = "".join(
            [
                "<html><body>",
                plotly.offline.plot(fig, output_type="div", include_plotlyjs="cdn"),
                "</body></html>",
            ]
        )

        plot_widget = WebEngineView()
        plot_widget.setHtml(html)

        self.setCentralWidget(plot_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

If you want to disable the contextmenu then you must set Qt.NoContextMenu as contextMenuPolicy:

```py
plot_widget.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.NoContextMenu)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works nearly perfectly, is there a way maybe to also remove the default actions from the menu?

Comment: @Flash333 only change to `menu = QMenu()`